# How to click on element if it is visible only after Mouse Over on to it?

Tags: protractor

I am trying to click on delete button which will be visible only if Hover Over the ng-repeat element.

```
HTML:

<div id="email-templates" class="email-templates" ng-repeat="template in templateList | orderBy: 'display_name'">
    <div class="template-name" aria-label="Changed Name" uib-tooltip="Changed Name" "="" ng-click="loadTemplate(template)" role="button" tabindex="0">
        <span>Changed Name</span>
        <div class="list-icon-container">
            <i class="template-delete template-report-icon icon delete-icon" tabindex="0" aria-label="Delete an Email Template" uib-tooltip="Delete an Email Template" ng-click="deleteTemplate(template)" role="button"></i>
            <i class="template-report-icon icon angle-right-icon icon-xs" tabindex="0"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 


   EmailTemplates Property File :

this.templateList = element.all(by.repeater("template in templateList"));
this.templateName = this.templateList.all(by.css('[ng-click="loadTemplate(template)"]'));
this.deleteBtn = this.templateName.all(by.css('[ng-click="deleteTemplate(template)"]'));
this.confirmDelete = element(by.css('button[translate="ZillaMain.DeleteModalConfirmButton"]'));

Test File: 
var EmailTemplates = require('../../.././pages/EmailTemplates');

describe('AddEmailTemplate-', function() {
it(TestSuiteName + 'Verify that User is able to Delete a Template', function() {
  var TempName = 'Test';
  EmailTemplates.templateName.getAttribute("aria-label").then(function(labels) {
    EmailTemplates.templateList.count().then(function(total) {
        console.log("total no of Email temp=" +total);
        for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            if (labels[i] === TempName) {                    
                console.log("Template Name found delete it :" +i);
                browser.actions().mouseMove(EmailTemplates.templateName.get(i)).perform().then(function(){
                                            browser.actions().mouseMove(EmailTemplates.deleteBtn.get(i)).click();
                        EmailTemplates.confirmDelete.click();
                        });

                } 
            }
       });
    });
  });
});
```

this gives me error every time: ***Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 5, but there are only 5 elements that match locator By(css selector, [ng-click="deleteTemplate(template)"])*** or ***element not visible.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are missing `perform()` after the browser actions chain (note that you could've spotted it earlier if you've used the [`eslint-plugin-protractor`](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor) ESLint plugin - there is a [`missing-perform` rule](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/docs/rules/missing-perform.md)).

And, after moving the mouse, try to *wait for the element to be clickable*:

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(EmailTemplates.templateName.get(i)).perform();

var deleteButton = EmailTemplates.deleteBtn.get(i);  
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(deleteButton), 5000);  

browser.actions().mouseMove(deleteButton).click().perform();
EmailTemplates.confirmDelete.click();
```

where `EC` is defined as:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
```

Comment: this is timing out after 5000 ms, I have added HTML also, not sure If I am identifying elements wrongly or what is the issue exactly? while my test is running I observed that MouseOver actually does not stay on the `templateName.get(i)` element. if Hover over `templateName.get(i)` element then only `deleteButton` will be visible.

Comment: @soniasharma ah, sure, spotted an issue. You are missing `perform()` call on your browser actions. Updated the answer.

Comment: @soniasharma sorry, I am an idiot, the `deleteButton` should be passed to the `mouseMove()`, fixed now, updated the answer.

Comment: again same issue `Failed: Wait timed out after 5008ms`

Comment: @soniasharma okay, we are on the right track. I had `perform()` missing in the first chain of actions, updated, please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131084/discussion-between-sonia-sharma-and-alecxe).